# Do I need to close a stream?

Tags: java

Do I need to close a FileOutputStream in the following example? And why?

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bytes.info");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(data);
oos.close();
```

Comment: If you mean `OutputStream` then **yes** you most definitely do. You should in fact **always** use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: While I'd suggest using a try-with-resources statement, `oos.close()` will close the `FileOutputStream` anyway.

Comment: @BoristheSpider than why this guy does not close it in an article  [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX99&S_CMP=CP]

Comment: stop downwoting and read the article - that guy does not close the `fos`

Comment: @furry that guy's code is horrible. Don't pay any attention to it. Many, if not most, articles on the internet feature badly written, incorrect, and damn right dangerous code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider And even that aside, tutorial code often concentrates on a single very specific aspect of the code and neglects others for the sake of simplicity. They shouldn't be used as general guides to coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were no exceptions thrown, then the `FileOutputStream` would be closed by `ooo.close()`.

An exception thrown in `writeObject` would prevent any of the streams from being closed. So the `close` call should be in a finally block.

There's the additional problem that the `ObjectOutputStream` could throw an exception in its constructor. It writes the stream header in the constructor which can cause an exception. In this case, the `FileOutputStream` needs to be closed, but calling `oos.close()` is not possible because there's no reference to the `ObjectOutputStream`. So you really need two separate calls to `close`, one for each stream, both in finally blocks.

Using try-with-resources takes care of all of this for you:

```
try(
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bytes.info");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
) {
    oos.writeObject(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to close the stream. Leaving `FileOutputStream` unclosed creates a possibility that some data that has been successfully written to the stream does not get saved to the file. If a program opens multiple file streams, not closing them creates a possibility of failures due to running out of native resources (too many files opened simultaneously).

`FileOutputStream` manages native resources, which are released by the `close` method. The class has a finalizer, too, which releases resources as well. As part of releasing native resources, the stream finishes out the writing of buffered data, if there is any. However, since JVM does not guarantee that a finalizer is going to be called on every object, failure to call `close` creates a risk of leaving buffered data unwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to close the FileOutputStream file. If not sometimes the data you save into the file might not get saved and you will end up with an empty file after executing the program. And you might wanna use try with resources so you won't have to close it manually and can do the exception handling part both at once.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bytes.info");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos));{

}catch(){}
```

Just in case if you are not using try with resources close the file streams in the finally block manually.

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

try{
      fos = new FileOutputStream("bytes.info");
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos));

      oos.writeObject(data);
   }catch(){
   }finally{
      if(fos != null){
         fos.close();
      }
      if(oos != null){
         oos.close();
      }
   }
```

It is a must to check whether those file streams are null or not. Because if they are null then there will be another error. Still it's better to use try with resources.

Comment: [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)`.close()` can throw `IOException`, so your second block should somehow deal with the case of `fos.close()` throwing it.